# Custom environments in Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I want to support more than the built-in "Development", "Staging", and "Production" environments that are defined in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.EnvironmentName`. I realize that I'm free to invent whatever names I wish when setting the environment during program initialization, but that's not the problem. There are 3 extension methods defined in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentExtensions` that are used seemingly *everywhere*: `IsDevelopment()`, `IsStaging()`, and `IsProduction()`.

How do you customize the behavior of `IsDevelopment()` so that multiple custom environment names each return true?

For example, I want to differentiate between local development and remote development; 2 environments with their own configuration settings, but both are considered "Development". Another example could be multiple "Staging" environments; one meant for internal testing, one meant for external/client testing, but both are considered "Staging".

I don't believe I can write my own IsDevelopment() extension method and safely assure that mine is always favored over Microsoft's ([Closer is better](https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/)). E.g. mine may be used by code in my project, but what about when code in Mvc itself calls it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is presently no way to do it, due to the existence and **usage** of the 3 `IsDevelopment()`, `IsStaging()`, and `IsProduction()` extension methods.

What I've basically ended up doing is defining my own custom environments, and provided a mapping from each back to the 3 defined in Asp.Net Core.

In Main(), I create an instance of my specialized configuration class; it figures out what custom environment the code's running in. Then, when I call WebHostBuilder.UseEnvironment(), I use a property from that class which indicates the Asp.Net Core environment that corresponds to my custom one. And, finally, I inject my class (singleton) into the DI container so it can be used as needed.